# itext5 - how to remove the empty space above a list in a PdfPCell

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I am using iText 5. I am following the example found here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150816002422/http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ListInCell

```
/**
 * This example was written by Bruno Lowagie for a prospective customer.
 * The code in this sample works with the latest version of iText.
 * It doesn't work with versions predating iText 5.
 */
 
package sandbox.tables;
 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
 
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.List;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
 
public class ListInCell {
 
  public static final String DEST = "results/tables/list_in_cell.pdf";
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new ListInCell().createPdf(DEST);
  }
 
  public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
 
    // This is how not to do it (but it works anyway):
 
    // We create a list:
    List list = new List();        
    list.add(new ListItem("Item 1"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item 2"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item 3"));
 
    // We wrap this list in a phrase:   
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
    phrase.add(list);
    // We add this phrase to a cell
    PdfPCell phraseCell = new PdfPCell();
    phraseCell.addElement(phrase);       
 
    // We add the cell to a table:
    PdfPTable phraseTable = new PdfPTable(2);
    phraseTable.setSpacingBefore(5);
    phraseTable.addCell("List wrapped in a phrase:");
    phraseTable.addCell(phraseCell);
 
    // We wrap the phrase table in another table:
    Phrase phraseTableWrapper = new Phrase();
    phraseTableWrapper.add(phraseTable);
 
    // We add these nested tables to the document:
    document.add(new Paragraph("A list, wrapped in a phrase, wrapped in a cell, wrapped in a table, wrapped in a phrase:"));
    document.add(phraseTableWrapper);
 
    // This is how to do it:
 
    // We add the list directly to a cell:
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.addElement(list);
 
    // We add the cell to the table:
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setSpacingBefore(5);
    table.addCell("List placed directly into cell");
    table.addCell(cell);
 
    // We add the table to the document:
    document.add(new Paragraph("A list, wrapped in a cell, wrapped in a table:"));
    document.add(table);
 
    // Avoid adding tables to phrase (but it works anyway):
 
    Phrase tableWrapper = new Phrase();
    tableWrapper.add(table);document.add(new Paragraph("A list, wrapped in a cell, wrapped in a table, wrapped in a phrase:"));
    document.add(tableWrapper);
 
    document.close();
  }
}
```

...and it gives a result similar to the sample PDF found here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140308004615/http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/list_in_cell.pdf

My issue is this: you can see that the text in each of the left cells ("list wrapped in a phrase...") is not lined-up horizontally with the first item of each list ("Item 1"). Specifically, I want to move up the text in the right cell's list. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set `cell.PaddingTop = -3f;` to move it up a little bit.